# Landscape Printing in Linux

Tags: printing, cups

I'm having trouble printing in landscape mode in a Gentoo (AMD64) installation.

The setup:

```
CUPS-1.7.5
CUPS-Filters-1.0.54
ghostscript-gpl-9.14
proprietary brother drivers

Printer: Brother DCP 7065dn
```

It will not print in landscape in any application (LO, acroread, evince etc..). Instead it is printing the proper image (e.g multiple pages are ordered as I would expect them to be in this mode) but in the wrong orientation. **Brlaser** (an alt. driver) doesn't offer duplex printing; and the printer works fine from a windows machine. In most applications I have no option of printer language, and in the ones which I do (namely acroread) it makes no difference.

This seems to be something of an ongoing problem in Linux, not just with this setup. Has anyone been able to overcome the problem?

Comment: I have a Brother HL5350DN and MFC6490CW both with brother drivers driven by an Ubuntu 12.04 system. No problems printing landscape for either of them (evince, LibreOffice, eog). cups 1.5.3, ghostscript 9.05

Comment: The problem seems to be constrained to various versions of CUPS, ghostscript, and printer drivers; a google of "linux landscape printing" reveals numerous problems with varying degrees of resolution.

Comment: Rotate your printer 90º and print....

Comment: Ok. that was a really bad joke. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Brlaser author here. From your question I can't tell if you have landscape printing problems with my driver or not. If you have, please [file a bug report on Github](https://github.com/pdewacht/brlaser/issues), preferably including a sample document and the printer settings used.

There's a chance you're just confused by the printer settings dialogs of the programs you've tested with:

- Evince has an "Auto rotate and center" option that's enabled by default. With that option the page orientation setting is effectively ignored.
- LibreOffice Writer has two page orientation options: one in the Page Style dialog and one in the Printer Settings dialog. I don't know how those two interact.

I wasn't aware the DCP-7065DN was a duplex printer. The person who tested brlaser with that model didn't mention it. I'll look into it, it should be pretty easy to get that working.